# Create dynamic form in Vue with conditional questions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I want to create a form dynamically, however, with conditional fields. The definition of the form is in an object Q.
Below example is a Vue component, using bootstrap-vue.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="q of Q">
            <br/>
            <template v-if="q.type == 'input'">
                {{ q.question }}
                <em v-if="q.comment"><br />{{ q.comment }}</em>
                <b-form-input v-model="q.value" :type="q.subtype" :placeholder="q.placeholder"></b-form-input>
                Value: {{ q.value }}
            </template>

            <template v-if="q.type == 'radio'">
                {{ q.question }}
                <em v-if="q.comment"><br />{{ q.comment }}</em>
                <b-form-group>
                    <b-form-radio-group buttons
                                        stacked
                                        v-model="q.value"
                                        :options="q.options"/>
                </b-form-group>

                Value: {{ q.value }}
            </template>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Questionnaire',
        data() {
            return {
                locale: 'en',
                Q: [
                    {
                        name: 'age',
                        value: null,
                        question: 'How old are you?',
                        placeholder: 'Your age...',
                        comment: 'years since you were born',
                        type: 'input',
                        subtype: 'number',
                        range: [18, 99],
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'cq',
                        value: null,
                        question: 'Conditional Question?',
                        type: 'radio',
                        options: [
                            {text: 'Yes', value: '0'},
                            {text: 'No', value: '1'},
                        ],
                        if: [{object: 'age', largerthan: 30}],
                    },
                ]
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onChange: function(){
                alert('test');
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

I want to show the "Conditional Question" only if the age > 30.

- In the object Q, I cannot access `this.Q` (because it does not exist yet).
- v-on:change="onChange" can work, however that defies the whole point of Vue

I'm not bound to this structure of the object, however it will be obtained using AJAX...

**the question**: Is there a way to watch `this.Q[0].value`? or other way to make the 2nd question available only if the first has a certain value?

Comment: Why not change your structure to use "key:value" pairs? Your array of objects contains 2 objects that are very different yet your structures it set up to treat them as if they are of the same type.

Comment: @Stephan-v Yes, that seems to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed creating the effect by using "v-if" directive on the 2nd div in your template.

Then I initialized the "Q" array by empty array and simulated AJAX request by setTimeout in the "created()" lifecycle hook.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="!(q.if) || Q[0].value > q.if[0].largerthan" v-for="q of Q">
        <br/>
        <template v-if="q.type == 'input'">
            {{ q.question }}
            <em v-if="q.comment"><br />{{ q.comment }}</em>
            <b-form-input v-model="q.value" :type="q.subtype" :placeholder="q.placeholder"></b-form-input>
            Value: {{ q.value }}
        </template>

        <template v-if="q.type == 'radio'">
            {{ q.question }}
            <em v-if="q.comment"><br />{{ q.comment }}</em>
            <b-form-group>
                <b-form-radio-group buttons
                                    stacked
                                    v-model="q.value"
                                    :options="q.options"/>
            </b-form-group>

            Value: {{ q.value }}
        </template>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Questionnaire',
    data() {
        return {
            locale: 'en',
            Q: [],
        };
    },
    created() {
      setTimeout( _ => this.Q = [
                {
                    name: 'age',
                    value: null,
                    question: 'How old are you?',
                    placeholder: 'Your age...',
                    comment: 'years since you were born',
                    type: 'input',
                    subtype: 'number',
                    range: [18, 99],
                },
                {
                    name: 'cq',
                    value: null,
                    question: 'Conditional Question?',
                    type: 'radio',
                    options: [
                        {text: 'Yes', value: '0'},
                        {text: 'No', value: '1'},
                    ],
                    if: [{object: 'age', largerthan: 30}],
                },
                {
                    name: 'age',
                    value: null,
                    question: 'How old are you?',
                    placeholder: 'Your age...',
                    comment: 'years since you were born',
                    type: 'input',
                    subtype: 'number',
                    range: [18, 99],
                },
         ], 500)
    },
}
```

Comment: The only "problem" with the code is that `Q[0]` is hard coded. I used your method, put the conditions in a method and added some more conditions. All seems to be working now!

Answer (score 2):

as what @Stephan-v says, I changed the object to a key:value object, instead of an array. As can be seen in the post of @Radovan-Šurlák, there is no need for a watcher. Do note that a computed object can only be created in "beforeCreate" and method, variables are not yet initialised. Passing variables from beforeCreate to the object seems rather difficult.

Thus using @Radovan-Šurlák as base, and improving it a bit results in:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(q, name) of Q" v-if="doShow( name )">
            <br/>
            <template v-if="q.type == 'input'">
                <b>{{ q.question }}</b>
                <em v-if="q.comment"><br/>{{ q.comment }}</em>
                <b-form-input v-model="q.value" :type="q.subtype" :placeholder="q.placeholder"></b-form-input>
            </template>

            <template v-if="q.type == 'radio'">
                <b>{{ q.question }}</b>
                <em v-if="q.comment"><br/>{{ q.comment }}</em>
                <b-form-group>
                    <b-form-radio-group buttons
                                        stacked
                                        v-model="q.value"
                                        :options="q.options"/>
                </b-form-group>
            </template>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Questionnaire',
        data() {
            return {
                locale: 'en',
                Q: {
                    age: {
                        value: null,
                        question: 'How old are you?',
                        placeholder: 'Your age...',
                        comment: 'years since you were born',
                        type: 'input',
                        subtype: 'number',
                        range: [18, 99],
                    },
                    cq: {
                        value: null,
                        question: 'Conditional Question?',
                        type: 'radio',
                        options: [
                            {text: 'Yes', value: '0'},
                            {text: 'No', value: '1'},
                        ],
                        if: [{object: 'age', largerthan: 30, smallerthan: 35, equals: 31, notequal: 32}],
                    },
                },
            };
        },
        methods: {
            doShow: function( field ) {
                for( var obj in this.Q[ field ].if )
                {
                    var ifObj = this.Q[ field ].if[ obj ];
                    if( ifObj.equals !== undefined && this.Q[ ifObj.object ].value != ifObj.equals )
                        return false;
                    if( ifObj.notequal !== undefined && this.Q[ ifObj.object ].value == ifObj.notequal )
                        return false;
                    if( ifObj.largerthan !== undefined && this.Q[ ifObj.object ].value <= ifObj.largerthan )
                        return false;
                    if( ifObj.smallerthan !== undefined && this.Q[ ifObj.object ].value >= ifObj.smallerthan )
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
            submit: function () {
                console.log('Submit form, send back data via Axios')
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            // Axios call
        }
    }
</script>
```